# Error: "use of unresolved identifier"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am making a face detection app. I have written some code for detection but I am getting an error. Kindly suggest me an alternate solution.
Here is the code, and the error is at line number 3.

```
import UIKit
import CoreImage

class ViewController: UIViewController ,UIAlertViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBAction func Moodify(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        picker.sourceType = .camera
        self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: { _ in })


        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
            let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]
            self.imageView!.image = chosenImage as? UIImage
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { _ in })
        }

        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { _ in })
        }

    }

    func detect() {

        guard let personciImage = CIImage(image: personPic.image!) else {
            return
        }

        let accuracy = [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh]
        let faceDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: accuracy)
        let faces = faceDetector.featuresInImage(personciImage)

        for face in faces as! [CIFaceFeature] {

            print("Found bounds are \(face.bounds)")

            let faceBox = UIView(frame: face.bounds)

            faceBox.layer.borderWidth = 3
            faceBox.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
            faceBox.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            personPic.addSubview(faceBox)

            if face.hasLeftEyePosition {
                print("Left eye bounds are \(face.leftEyePosition)")
            }

            if face.hasRightEyePosition {
                print("Right eye bounds are \(face.rightEyePosition)")
            }
        }
    }    

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Device has no camera", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


    /*    if !UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            let myAlertView = UIAlertView (title: "Error", message: "Device has no camera", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK", otherButtonTitles: "")
            myAlertView.show()
        }  */

        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

[image: SEE ERROR IN THIS IMAGE]

Comment: Where is defined `personPic`? From where it comes?

Comment: Where is `personPic` declared?

Comment: Also why did you reject my edit? It fixes the broken formatting in your question. Currently your image isn't accesable.

Comment: Yet Nirav suggets the same edit a minute later and you approve it? I'm confused.

Comment: I did not see the image in your suggestion dear.

Comment: @JacobKing how can i declare and where, i have defined in at line 3

Comment: You are not declaring it, you're trying to reference your already declared object. I suspect you haven't already declared it and hence you are getting that error.

Comment: @Larme i am learning from appcoda.com so i copied from that site and further trying to modify code

Comment: thankyou so much @JacobKing can you help me to declare?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the whole source file.

Comment: @JacobKing suggest edit with image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare it and connect to a UIImageView in storyboard.

```
@IBOutlet weak var personPic: UIImageView!
```

This is basic of programming. How can you use something that you haven't declared, right? Ok good luck in your project.

Comment: Thank you so much dear, I replaced the personPic with my imageView that I connected as an IBOutlet. now it does not show any error.